# Calculation of portion quantities

Tags: jquery, html

I am currently trying to style a kind of cookbook and are currently reaching my limits :). Probably simple, but currently I can not come up with a good solution.

The site admin creates recipes with ingredient quantities which are entered in conjunction with a portion amount (e.g., number of persons).
Now I would like to have the amount of ingredients calculated when the visitor of the website changes the portion amount.

Maybe someone can help me, HTML currently looks like this:

```
<div class="row ingredients">
    <div class="col col-md-6 ingredientlist">
        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="quantity-unit">
                    <span class="quantity">550</span>
                    <span class="unit">g</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label">XXX</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="quantity-unit">
                    <span class="quantity">50</span>
                    <span class="unit">g</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label">YYY</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-md-6 portions">
        <h2><input class="portionsamount" type="number" min="0" max="1000" value="12">Portions</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Each "li>div.quantity-unit" should therefore calculate the ".quantity" with the ".portionsamount".

The calculation should then work like this:
(.quantity / .portionsamount) * new.quantity <- this can be the entered variable.

Thanks in advance
Nico

Comment: What is your `new.quantity`? And what is `.quantity`? YYY or XXX? Unclear info. What is editable, what is static?

Comment: XXX and YYY is only a Labelname of the ingredients (f.e. sugar or something).
. portionsamount is editable, but it's preset by the admin.

Comment: What do you mean under `.quantity` and `new.quantity`? You wanna change these 2 numbers via changing `.portionsamount` range number? Am I right?

Comment: Oh sorry. "new.quantity" should named in "new. portionsamount". I have written the term only once to clarify how the calculation could be. So if the visitor changes portionsamount.

Comment: for example 550/12*new? or 550*new? same with 50g

Comment: For a better understanding: https://ibb.co/jyVKkFd.

I hope it helps: P

Comment: 12 is the default value for this recipe. This can be different in every recipe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little bit hard to understand your last formula -> `(.quantity / .portionsamount) * new.quantity`. What about this snippet?
It is multiplying 550g/12 (and 50g/12) on `range value`.

```js
  

var ar = []; // array of ingrid-s
var i = 0;   // counter
var dq = Number($('.def_quant').text());   // default value (first one was 12)
$('.portionsamount').val(dq);              // set class="portionsamount" value = default value

$('.quantity').each(function(){             // array of g/def_value 
   ar[i] = Number($(this).text())/dq; 
   i++;
}); 

$('.portionsamount').change(function(){ 

    var p = Number($(this).val());  // chosen value
    var o = 0;                      // counter

    $('.quantity').each(function(){ // set formula value to each ingrid 
        $(this).text((ar[o]*p*100).toFixed()/100); 
        o++;
    });    
});
$('.portionsamount').change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row ingredients">
    <div class="col col-md-6 ingredientlist">
        <h2>Ingredients</h2>
        <ul>            
            <div class="def_quant" style="display:none;">12</div>
            <li>
                 <div class="quantity-unit">
                     <span class="quantity">440</span>
                     <span class="unit">g</span>
                 </div>
                 <span class="label">XXX</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="quantity-unit">
                    <span class="quantity">550</span>
                    <span class="unit">g</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label">XXX</span>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="quantity-unit">
                    <span class="quantity">50</span>
                    <span class="unit">g</span>
                </div>
                <span class="label">YYY</span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-md-6 portions">
        <h2><input class="portionsamount" type="number" min="0" max="1000">Portions</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow that's almost perfect. Many thanks!

I never know how many ingredients there are, can this be made variable?
And the next step would be, how to make the 12 can read from a DIV?

Comment: @Nico, check it.

Comment: Wow, that's it! Thank you so much :)